# $L^2$ space (or just integration) on $\Omega \times \{0,1\}$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded domain. If $u \in L^2(\Omega \times \{0,1\})$, then $$\int_{\Omega \times \{0,1\}}|u(x,y)|^2 < \infty$$.

How to interepret the integral $\int_{\Omega \times \{0,1\}}f(x,y)$? I expect it to be equal to $\int_{\Omega} f(x,0) + \int_{\Omega} f(x,1)$, but I don't know if it is true.

Edit: I think we can write $\Omega \times \{0,1\} = \Omega \times \{0\} \cup \Omega \times \{1\}$ and then split the integral which gives us
$$\int_{\Omega \times \{0\}}f(x,y) + \int_{\Omega \times \{1\}}f(x,y)$$
and then..?

Comment: Depends on the measure $\mu$ one puts on $E=\Omega\times\{0,1\}$. For $\mu=\nu\otimes(\delta_0+\delta_1)$, indeed, $$\int_E fd\mu=\int_\Omega f(\cdot,0)d\nu+\int_\Omega f(\cdot,1)d\nu$$ but tons of other choices are available.

Comment: @Did If I have $X= \Omega \times [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and I consider $\Omega \times \{0,1\}$ in my OP as a (parabolic?) boundary of $X$, then is the measure in your comment the one that naturally I give this space?

Comment: With Lebesgue measure... on [0,1], you mean? But for which measure on X?

Comment: @Did I meant give $X=\Omega \times [0,1]$ the product Lebesgue measure. Then is it natural (or even necessary) to give $\partial X = \Omega \times \{0,1\}$ the measure in your OP.

Comment: @Upin For example, $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $X=\Omega\times [0,1]$ is equipped with the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Then the integral over $\Omega\times\{0,1\}$ is just zero.

Comment: @Upin Yes, with $\nu$ Lebesgue on $\Omega$.

Comment: @A.G. Hmm, I understand that $\Omega \times \{0,1\}$ is null with the product (2d) Lebesgue measure. But my question is what should I choose as a measure?

Comment: @A.G. One can, and one routinely does, put non trivial measures on $\Omega\times\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @Upin Ok, so you do not have any *apriori* measure on the product space and you question is how to pick it smart to get the sum?

Comment: @A.G. No, on $X$ I have the Lebesgue measure. I guess the questions are: 1) What should the measure be on $\partial  X= \Omega \times \{0,1\}$ to get what I want in my OP? 2) Is that choice of measure natural? Question 1 was answered in Did's first comment.

Comment: @Did Thanks. Just to clarify, you are saying that, given (as I wrote) that I give $X$ the product Lebesgue measure, that this necessarily implies that the boundary $\partial X=\Omega \times \{0,1\}$ has $\nu \otimes (\delta_0 + \delta_1)$, right? Can I ask why? (I guess given a Riem. manifold with boundary, its boundary is endowed with some induced measure).

Comment: Not necessarily, only a natural choice is to avoid favoring 0 over 1 or the opposite, since one starts from a symmetrical situation on X. For a general construction of a measure on some part Y of X with global measure zero, one can start from the global measure restricted to the set Y_t of the points in X at distance less than t from Y, and consider the limit, possibly renormalized, when t go to 0.